# What is the correct way to structure membership in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have a site that includes teams and members. I have a team model and a member model:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = CharField()

class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    team = models.ManyToManyField(Team)
```

In this relationship, `Team` and `Member` are directly related using a `ManyToManyField` (members can have more than one team).

This would mean that I add and remove members from teams in the view like so:

```
team.objects.add(member)  # Add a member to a team
team.objects.remove(member)  # remove a member from a team
```

The alternative is to remove the `ManyToMany` relationship and make a "Membership" model between teams and members, like so:

```
class Membership(models.Model):
    is_active = BooleanField(default=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
```

This way, to link a member to a team I would `get_or_create` a `Membership` instance. To remove or re-add the member to the team, I would switch the `is_active` flag, rather than `add()` or `remove()` the `ManyToMany` relationship.

Is it more error-prone to `add()` and `remove()` members from a team using the direct relationship, or is it better to use a `get_or_create` on an intermediate `Membership` model?

Or, is either correct and fine to use?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking here: 'is it more error-prone' seems to be quite a subjective question. Note you can combine the approaches by setting Membership as the `through` parameter to the ManyToManyField.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've heard that using `add()` and `remove()` could be more error-prone at the database level rather than simply flipping a flag on an intermediate model? Maybe that isn't the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really need is to decide -> do you need an [extra data on your M2M relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)? Because your intermediate model is just that. And I can't find it as a less error-prone, the main difference with it's `is_active` flag is that this gives you something like a historical info about the past memberships. Do you need this data? If you do - go with that approach. If you are just doing it because you think its less error-prone, then for me you are solving the wrong problem.

Comment: "solving the wrong problem"; which is the real problem with the OP's approach.